# Rendering NULL values with joined CSV file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, symbology, attribute-joins

I have a set of polygons in a single shapefile layer. I have added a data table as a new layer and joined the two layers. Some of my polygons do not have entries in the data layer and consequently, they are not rendered at all.

I could of course add entries to my data table, but is there a way I can show these missing polygons?

[image: missing polygons]

In the image there are many missing polygons in the larger white spaces.

Here is the join between the data and the layer.

[image: join]

and here is the symbology:

[image: symbology]

There are many missing polygons in the larger white areas (the ones with the blue dots are a few examples). This image shows some of the missing ones that appear if I turn the Graduated Symbology off. I am sure the reason is that my shapefile layer is linked to a text layer that does not have entries for all the polygons. So they are `NULL` I guess rather than `0`. What I need is the ability to show the polygons with no data.

[image: missing polygons]

Comment: You question is unclear: can you post a screenshot? If you have a polygon layer, same of the polygons can have `NULL` values for some of the fields - this does not affect visibility of the polygon at all. So please be more precise and describe what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the post.

Comment: Can you describe or add a screenshot of how you joined the two layers?

Comment: Do you use a categorized renderer? Can you share your project +data? Wirh the information you provided, it's not possible to see what the problem is.

Comment: I have added a bit of clarity, I hope, as to what I mean by the 'missing' polygons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1

Use `Categorized` instead of `Graduated` layer rendering style, set you attribute field `Compton1_Nonconformists` as input for `Value` and click `Classify`. For every value contained in this field, you will get a separate color + another one for `all other values`, thus including `NULL`.

### Solution 2

If you do not have fixed values, but stepless values with no two identical ones, stick to your initial solution, but duplicate the layer and apply a style for only the polygons with `NULL` values.

*Solution 1: Polygons with `value` = `NULL` are contained in the category `all other values`, thus blue:*
[image]